# Print the Sum of the largest of two numbers with the collections of array method?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;

class Sumlarge
{
    public static void main(String...s)
    {
        int a[]=new int[5];
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 5 Numbers");  
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Before Sorting");
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++) 
        {
            System.out.println(a[j]);
        }
        Arrays.sort( a );
        System.out.println("After Sorting");
        for(int j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
                System.out.println(a[j]);
        }
        Sum.Ob = new Sum();
        Ob.Sum1(a[5],a[4]);
    }
}


class Sum 
{ 
    void Sum1(int a,int b)
    {   
        int add;  
        add=a+b;
        System.out.println("Sum is"+add);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `collection of array method` ?

Comment: Please.. ask a question.

Comment: i used arrays class method

Comment: i am having error in this code

Comment: If you have an error, please describe that error, and include any stacktrace.

Comment: line number 24 & 25 is error line as per cmd

Comment: Instead of `Sum.Ob` you meant `Sum Ob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line `Sum.Ob = new Sum();` will certainly throw an error. Did you mean to write `Sum Ob = new Sum();`? Anyway, there is no need for the `Sum` class at all. Replace these lines:

```
Sum.Ob = new Sum();
Ob.Sum1(a[5],a[4]);
```

with this:

```
int sum = a[4] + a[3];
```

Note: use index 4 and 3, because indexes start at 0.

Answer (score 1):

This is incorrect,

```
Sum.Ob = new Sum();
Ob.Sum1(a[5],a[4]);
```

Your class is named `Sum`. You can have an instance named `ob`;

```
if (a.length > 2) {
  Sum ob = new Sum();
  ob.Sum1(a[a.length-1], a[a.length-2]); // <-- use length
}
```

Finally, your method `Sum1` should really have a different name (starting with a lower case letter). Maybe, `printSum(int, int)` - but really adding two numbers and printing the result hardly seems to merit a method.